# What is the meaning of "a sense of failure over never..."

Tags: meaning

> Logue is a man who must cure his own demons – **a sense of failure over never having made it as a professional actor** – and who is everywhere patronised as a colonial.

Sense of failure didn't allow him to become an actor or he didn't become an actor and it oppresses him now?

Comment: sense of failure about the fact he never became a professional actor. We say: to have sense of x about or over verb+ ing etc.

Answer (score 1):

The word **over** here means: **with regard to the subject of, in terms of, concerning, etc.**

a sense of failure **over** [**with regard to, about, concerning, on the subject of**] never having made it as a professional actor

With words relating to situations, you will often find this word **over**,

- We had a disagreement **over** the money she owed me.
- I felt very bad **over** the situation that had developed.
- He had a sense of failure **over** the way the situation was handled.

Answer (score 0):

"never having made it as a professional actor" does not mean that he never became a professional actor. It means that he did, but was not successful in that profession. He was always the chap who came on stage carrying a spear but with no words to speak, rather than the man who played Hamlet.